# how to filter MPMediaItems by .mp3 files to play songs in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, mpmediaquery

I need to filter my query items by .mp3 files. Now i am getting result from query,it's contains video files(mp4). these are my line of codes

```
 MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
        NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
        self.songs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemsFromGenericQuery];
```

Comment: Did you try `[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the songs in the library use `-[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]` instead of creating your own MPMediaQuery.

If you're looking for local .mp3 files specifically, you add a filter for the property `MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem`, and then check `-[MPMediaItem assetURL]` to determine if the file matches.